# How to seal new PVC to old Lead pipe "toilet bend"

Tags: plumbing, toilet, pvc, adhesive, lead

I have an old toilet flange which was a brass ring on a 4" lead bend that connects to the main cast iron stack. The old brass flange ring corroded and broke. I found a nice PVC fitting that fits snugly  inside the old lead bend [from Oatey](http://www.oatey.com/products/drains-and-closet-flanges/closet-flanges/level-fit-closet-flange-with-plastic-ring) but now I need to find a sealant that will adhere to both the lead and the PVC. Or at least to the PVC.

I was going to use the fitting that has the mechanicaly expanding rubber gasket, but this is too long and hits a radius of the pipe before the flange itself is fully seated to the floor.

[image: The PVC fitting]

Comment: The expanding flange that you had is the proper way to fix it -- how much farther would it need to go?

Comment: These lead elbows are very soft, I would not use any compression band to do any connection. If the side of the lead pipe buckled, it would be bad. Better to take out the whole lead part and replace it with a neoprene hub adapter and PVC pipe and elbow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Term Update:
I did use one of these "expanding" repair flanges and it was fine. It's been over two years since the repair with no issues!

Toilet Flange
OATEY Mfr #: 43539

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you will need to replace the lead closet bend with pvc or abs use a no hub coupler to connect the lead to the plastic pipe

Comment: Can you say why removing the old closet bend would be necessary here?